# Unable to set element sticky despite setting position sticky

Tags: html, css

I have a layout as:

[image: screenshot]

I want this left and right sidebar to be sticky.

Here, is my code:

```css
/** Header Row Starts **/
.fs-header-row {
  background: #ffffff;
  /* height: 61px; */
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: grid;
}
/** Header Row Ends **/

.main-fs-container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lime;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 279px auto;
}
/** Left Sidebar Starts **/
.fs-sidebar-left {
  width: 279px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 12px 10px 12px 15px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
/** Left Sidebar Ends **/
/** Main Container Starts **/
.building-table-container {
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
}
.floor-stack-main {
  /* margin-left: 289px; */
  padding: 14px 14px 100px 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.floor-stack-main .building-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/** Main Container Ends **/
/**right column starts**/
.floor-stack-main .unit-detail-right {
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 61px; */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
.floor-stack-main .unit-detail-right .unit-detail-wrapper {
  width: 279px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
  padding: 13px 12px;
}
/** right column ends **/
```

```html
<div class="App">
   <div class="fs-header-row">
      <p>This is just the replica of a header row</p>
   </div>
   <div class="main-fs-container">
      <aside class="fs-sidebar-left">
         <div class="ks-first-row d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <h2 class="sidebar-title mb-0">Left SIdebar needs to be stikcy</h2>
         </div>
         <div class="ks-second-row toggle-button-groups">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste voluptatem cumque excepturi earum velit id laudantium quod, temporibus minima maiores quam officiis quia numquam. Voluptatem ad minima tempore consequuntur a.</p>
         </div>
      </aside>
      <div class="floor-stack-main">
         <div class="buildings-column">
            <div class="building-table-container">
               <h5 class="building-title">Building 1</h5>
               <div class="ks-building-wrapper">
                  <table class="table">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Company</th>
                           <th>Contact</th>
                           <th>Country</th>
                           <th>Dummy1</th>
                           <th>Dummy2</th>
                           <th>Dummy3</th>
                           <th>Dummy4</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
           
            <div class="building-table-container">
               <h5 class="building-title">Building 1</h5>
               <div class="ks-building-wrapper">
                  <table class="table">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Company</th>
                           <th>Contact</th>
                           <th>Country</th>
                           <th>Dummy1</th>
                           <th>Dummy2</th>
                           <th>Dummy3</th>
                           <th>Dummy4</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                           <td>Maria Anders</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                           <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="unit-detail-right">
            <div class="unit-detail-wrapper">
               <h2>Right Sidebar,</h2>
               <h4>this needs to be sticky</h4>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto non possimus veniam laudantium molestiae numquam, quas facilis totam impedit, adipisci quibusdam perferendis beatae explicabo, quasi reprehenderit unde labore debitis eveniet?</p>

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/95o6t0xb/).

On this one, right sidebar needs to be sticky, in more like a fixed or absolute way. For example, the table on the green background can extended upto right even on that case right sidebar needs to be above this green div and still needs to be sticky.

How could I make these two sidebars sticky?

Comment: use ```align-self: start``` on the thing you want to be sticky.

Comment: @norbekoff THank you, this works for left column but how could I achieve it on right sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in how the HTML structure is presented.

Sticky content has to:

- Be able to identify the height of its parent.
- That parent should be larger than the content (so that there is room for it to move).
- There should be no overflow properties.
- A position of `top` has to be given a value.

Your left sidebar has `position: sticky` on the wrong element. Instead of `.fs-sidebar-left { position: sticky }`, you should have it on the child element(s) `.ks-first-row / .ks-second-row`; if you want both to be contained together, wrap them with a div and put the position sticky on that instead.

Your right sidebar is using `position: absolute`, so this isn't set to be sticky.

Here's a quick example you can use to layout your content to allow position sticky to work.

[Here's a working example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lmonk72/pen/rNdVYqp)

Comment: Thank you it helps. Main reason why it was not running in my case was, overflow hidden in the root wrapper.